# How to fix favicon.ico error: "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE"

Tags: html, netbeans

I downloaded the Netbeans IDE to code in HTML. When I run my code, chrome is opening and everything is working just fine. I'm getting some sort of error in the Output - Browser Log.

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE (20:00:55:963 | error, network)
at http://localhost:8383/favicon.ico
```

How do I fix it?

Comment: Reading this from seven years in the future... every time I have this problem, the solution is different from the previous time. What I'm getting in FF is no error once, but all subsequent reloads show the error. Solution from element11 solved it (this time).

Comment: In my case, it was fixed by moving the `favicon.ico` to the same place as my Html file. Obviously, you should change the icon path too.

Answer (score 324, accepted):

I have had this error for some time as well. It might be some kind of netbeans bug that has to do with netbeans connector. I can't find any mention of `favicon.ico` in my code or in the project settings.

I was able to fix it by putting the following line in the `head` section of my html file

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="#">
```

I am currently using this in my testing environment, but I would remove it for any production environment.

Comment: I don't think it has to do with NetBeans. It happens whenever you do `cordova run browser`.

Comment: For me it happened now while being inside a directory of my website. But it pointed to the root directory looking for a favicon.ico. I am using Chrome...

Comment: It has nothing to do with NetBeans, I use Eclipse, PyCharm etc and I get the same error.

Comment: This solution might not be correct, as I have tried it, and it doesn't work. Still getting the error.

Comment: @Tamas yeap the same for me, the answer below should be the correct one

Comment: Only with `href="#"` wokring ref. https://stackoverflow.com/a/43791570/248616

Comment: message disappeared when I removed all my chrome extensions

Comment: Instead of `href="#"`, which can cause some browsers to re-request the page, use `<link rel="icon" href="data:,">` to prevent any request, per https://stackoverflow.com/a/38917888/1327983

Comment: Just ran into this issue. It is specific to favicons. Create a favicon.svg file and apply the path to your favicon in your link tag href attribute and then rebuild client.

Comment: This worked for me but why it happened and why it is solved with this addition?

Answer (score 184):

The accepted answer didn't work for me, I had to add a value to the href attribute:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="#" />
```

Comment: The accepted answer did not work for me either. Thanks for posting this...it worked me (in chrome).

Comment: Yeah this removes the error in Chrome when hosting my HTML page on AWS S3. Without it I get a 403 error for favicon.ico, despite the fact that there was no reference to a favicon in the code.

Comment: Do we need to specify any mime type for this?

Comment: This will trigger the double fetching of the document in some browsers (including Chrome), see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2009092/page-loads-twice-in-google-chrome

Comment: @kursus: The problem seems to be suppressed in Sr Julien answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/40527353/669527

Comment: BE CAREFUL if you're using this option. If you're using a filter in a web project this might cause it to get called twice as I answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16646819/dofilter-called-twice-intended-behaviour/60557875#60557875 . I recommend calling a valid icon it's that simple.

Comment: same here. thanks for posting this. it work for me as well.

Comment: Agree! This should be th accepeted one.

Answer (score 39):

The accepted answer didn't work for me so I've found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1321878/how-to-prevent-favicon-ico-requests#).

It may be related to the HTML version as the most voted solution there states:

> If you need your document to validate against HTML5 use this instead:
>
> ```html
> <link rel="icon" href="data:;base64,iVBORw0KGgo=">
> ```

See the link for more info.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13416784/1705829) is the link to the solution, not the question.

Answer (score 39):

The answers above didn't work for me. I found a [**very good article for Favicon**](http://www.webweaver.nu/html-tips/favicon.shtml), explaining:

- what is a Favicon;
- why does Favicon.ico show up as a 404 in the log files;
- why should You use a Favicon;
- how to make a Favicon using [**FavIcon from Pics**](http://www.chami.com/html-kit/services/favicon/) or other Favicon
  creator;
- how to get Your Favicon to show.

So I created Favicon using `FavIcon from Pics`. Put it in folder (named favicon) and add this code in `<head>` tag:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon/favicon.ico">
<link rel="icon" type="image/gif" href="favicon/animated_favicon1.gif">
```

**Now there is no error and I see my Favicon:**

[image]

Comment: Tried this... everything works fine in my local but when I deploy to servers I am getting this error..

Comment: @Petya Kostova, thanks for the link! Very helpful. Just to add one more link, [this article](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/rel-shortcut-icon) explains how `icon` is for Chrome/Firefox/etc while `shortcut icon` is for IE, just for anyone (like me) who was curious why you need both.

Answer (score 25):

favicon.ico is the icon of a website on the title bar of your website. 
Netbeans couldnt find the favicon.ico file in your website folder

if you dont want it, you can remove the line that is similar to this in your head section

```
 <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">
```

or if you want to use an icon for the title bar, you can use [icon convertor](http://convertico.com/) to generate a .ico image and keep it in your website folder and use the above line in the head section

Comment: There is no icon like that in my head section.

Comment: Please post your head section html code, it is difficult to solve an error without seeing the code

Comment: The thing is that `/favicon.ico` is always requested automatically by browsers or servers, nowadays, if there is no `<link rel="shortcut icon">`. If you provide a different URI in this `<link>`, then that URI is requested instead. There is nothing to remove.

Answer (score 14):

For me the answer didn't work too, but this work fine:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="data:image/x-icon;," type="image/x-icon">
```

Comment: This solves the problem without causing double fetching.

Answer (score 5):

You can provide your own image and reference it in the head, for example:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico">
```

Answer (score 3):

Also, be careful so your href location isn't faulty.
Study case:

My index page was in a temporary sub-folder named LAYOUTS.
To reach the favicon.png from inside the IMAGES folder, which was a sibling of the LAYOUTS folder, I had to put a path in my href like this

```
href="../images/favicon-32x32.png"
```

**Double periods are necessary for folder navigation "upwards"**, then the forward slash + `images` string gets you into the images folder (performing a tree branch "jump") and finally you get to reference your file by writing `favicon-32x32.png`.

This explanation is useful for those that start out from scratch and it would have been useful to have seen it a couple of times since I would forget that I had certain *.php files outside the LAYOUTS folder which needed different tree hrefs on my links, from the HEAD section of each page.

Reference the path to your favicon image accordingly.

Comment: I'm not sure if it is good to use relative paths directly.  I typically use @Url.Content("~/Images/favicon.ico") if using MVC or ASP.NET Web API to resolve URLs fully before sending down to the client.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the below tag inside the head tag:

```
<link rel="icon" href="#" />
```

Do ctrl + R for refresh or ctrl + shift + R for hard refresh the page to see the  result

Comment: Please do not post duplicate answers, comment or vote up instead. This was used in the accepted and highly user-confirmed answer.

Answer (score 2):

This problem occurs when you do not declare at the top of your HTML file in HEDER this tag.

```
<link rel="icon" href="your_address_icon" type="image/x-icon">
```

Answer (score 2):

add this code in  your page index

```
<link rel="icon" 
      type="image/png" 
      href="http://example.com/myicon.png">
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a nightmare since each browser/device handles it differently.

Favicon generator helps me a lot for those applications where we need to cover the most possible scenarios.

https://realfavicongenerator.net/

You just need a png image 260px x 260px (at least) and from there the generator will create all references you need within your web page.

You just need to add this references and images to your application.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If favicon is in the root:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="../favicon.ico" />
```

Answer (score 1):

## Server Configuration Nginx

If you are deploying your application to a server that is running Nginx, you may use the following configuration file as a starting point for configuring your web server. Most likely, this file will need to be customized depending on your server's configuration. If you would like assistance in managing your server, consider using a first-party Laravel server management and deployment service.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name example.com;
    root /srv/example.com/public;
 
    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";
 
    index index.php;
 
    charset utf-8;
 
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }
 
    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
 
    error_page 404 /index.php;
 
    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
 
    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

edit these line into site-avalible in your files.

```
 location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
```

## Optimization - Autoloader Optimization

When deploying to production, make sure that you are optimizing Composer's class autoloader map so Composer can quickly find the proper file to load for a given class:

`composer install --optimize-autoloader --no-dev`

thankyou! @syedasadrazadevops

Answer (score 0):

I had a weird situation. Mine was working fine and all of sudden stopped with that error message. I already had the header declaration. So I was dumb founded as to why it wasn't working.

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.png">
```

Literally nothing else on the site had an issue that I could tell. The only thing that **fixed** it for me was to restart my Apache service and all was good again.

if nothing else is working, give that a shot and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same fav icon error - 404 (Not Found). I used the following element in the `<head>` element of my index.html file and it fixed the error:

```
<link rel="icon" href="data:;base64,iVBORw0KGgo=">
```

Comment: An explanation in how this fixes the error would very helpful, consider  adding come details about your answer.

Answer (score 0):

In `Angular` earlier we had `.angular-cli.json` file which referred to `favicon.ico`. If you'll upgrade into one of the newer versions of `Angular` then you'll have `angular.json` instead. For these newer versions, you have to refer the favicon path in your `index.html` from now onwards.

Answer (score 0):

I copied the favicon.ico to assets folder its worked for me .

Answer (score 0):

Try this add "icon" with your stylesheet Maybe it solve your error "favicon.ico:1 not found "

OR
First Try to understand about favicon.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pdoCs.jpg)
SET your favicon icon file in your folder. You can generate your favicon using "https://favicon.io/favicon-generator/".

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else is running into a 403 error after downloading a favicon package, I needed to chmod the new favicon folder/file permissions to 755 so Apache had permission to read the file.

Answer (score 0):

i was getting the same problem (using thymeleaf) i solved by downloading the bootstrap link that i'm using on my html to my spring-boot-project
just hover your mouse over the link and your IDE (ps :intellij is the best) will propose to you to downloaded & and bom problem solved

Answer (score 0):

Today we catched this error in our production environment (everything still fine on the test server). No advice in this discussion helped. Error raised on one particular php script. I scattered debug printing inside it, no results.
Next, I checked error log and found a lot of strings:

AH00052: child pid NNNNNN exit signal Segmentation Fault (11)

Then I asked our admin to restart Apache server. And wow, that error disappeared!
I don't know, what exactly in apache becomes broken after some working period (one of php modules or apache itself).
Unfortunately, after a few working hours, net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE came back.