# mqtt cordova visualstudio2015 : Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2015, cordova-plugins, mqtt, visual-studio-cordova

MQTT Plugin : https://www.npmjs.com/package/mqtt
I installed MQTT Plugin using

> npm install mqtt --save

And, also i did below step
Browserify

> ```
> 1.npm install -g browserify // install browserify
> 2.cd node_modules/mqtt
> 3.npm install . // install dev dependencies
> 4.browserify mqtt.js -s mqtt > browserMqtt.js // require mqtt in your client-side app
> ```

Webpack

> ```
> 1.npm install -g webpack // install webpack
> 2.cd node_modules/mqtt
> 3.npm install . // install dev dependencies
> 4.webpack mqtt.js ./browserMqtt.js --output-library mqtt
> ```

And i added like this in my `.html` file

```html
    <script src="../browserMqtt.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/paho-mqttws31.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/mqtt.js"></script>
```

and i also added in my `.js` file

```js
const mqtt = require("mqtt");
```

and i have got errors.

> paho-mqttws31.js:2268 Uncaught ReferenceError: module is not defined
>   at paho-mqttws31.js:2268 (anonymous) @ paho-mqttws31.js:2268
>   =>if(module && module.exports) module.exports=Paho;
>
> mqtt.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined at mqtt.js:1
>   =>var Paho = require('cordova-plugin-mqtt-pahojs.paho_mqttws31');

these two error are occurred and '=>' mark is pointed to a place which is occurring error.

So, i have deleted this two

then i got one error that

> Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

and linked as error occurring position

And i got one more error :

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) 4400/favicon.ico

[I'm getting favicon.ico error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31075893/im-getting-favicon-ico-error)

[I'm getting favicon.ico error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31075893/im-getting-favicon-ico-error/31329574)

I have searched and been applying some references above. However, it didn't work at all.

Comment: I fixed this problem. In your config.xml, add your plugin like this   <plugin name="cordova-plugin-mqtt" version="0.3.8" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" version="2.0.1" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-mqtt-pahojs" version="1.5.2" />

Comment: And if you are using visual studio, you can ignore favicon error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this problem. In your config.xml, add your plugin like this

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-mqtt" version="0.3.8" /> <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" version="2.0.1" /> 
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-mqtt-pahojs" version="1.5.2" />
```

And if you are using visual studio, you can ignore favicon error.