# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://eluxer.net/code?sesscheck=1&id=105&subid=51824_5848_

Tags: google-chrome, visual-studio-code, livereload, npm-live-server

I use live-server to live reload folder with `HTML`, `javascript` and `CSS` files using `Visual Studio Code`.

When I open the console in Google Chrome I see this

[image: error message]:

> "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
>   (Not Found)
>   http://eluxer.net/code?sesscheck=1&id=105&subid=51824_5848_"

I tried this with many different folders and every time there is the same message with live-server. Аt the same time, there is no error message when I open the `HTML` file direct in the browser (without live-server).

Please, Can anyone tell me how to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**I fixed the problem making this steps:**

- **Clear cache and cookies.** [Here](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/32050?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en) You can see how.
- **Reset Chrome** this way: Click on "Customize and control Google Chrome" in the upper right corner => Click on "Settings" => then "Advanced" => "Reset and clean up" => "Reset" => Restart Chrome.
- **Uninstall Chrome.** For `Windows 10` is this way: Close all Chrome windows and tabs => Right click on the "Start menu" => Click "Apps and Features" => Click on `Google Chrome` => Click "Uninstall" => (The current step will delete your user profile information, like your browser preferences, bookmarks and history, so if You want to save it, do it in advance! Mine profile information was save in my Google account.) Check this box "Also delete your browsing data" and click "Uninstall". Here is a [video tutorial "How to uninstall Google Chrome web browser and remove all Google Chrome files from Your computer"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fgvjwq6rDz0).
- **Install fresh copy of Google Chrome**

**After all this, The Error was gone but I had a new one:**

[image]

**I removed this error [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31075893/im-getting-favicon-ico-error/#50052294).**

**Finally all is clear:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue.

If you are just testing / developing. You can use **Incognito**, `ctrl+shift+n`
mode this quickly  clears the issue and you can proceed with testing/dev.

But please follow the other steps for a permanent fix.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I got the error because I was having issues trying to load a picture that the server could not find.

I solved by moving the picture from the root location to

```
\wwwroot\images\picture.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the error may be;
You may not have defined the js file in the body with the script tag.