# XMLHttpRequest returning status 0

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, html, xmlhttprequest

I'm just writing my first JavaScript code today. On my local machine I'm running:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Admin</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <script>
        function myTable()
        {
            var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
            var url = "MYSERVERADDRESS/login.php";
            var params = "username=ABC&password=123";

            http.open("POST", url, true);
            http.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            http.onreadystatechange = function() {
                document.write("state = " + http.readyState + ", status = " + http.status);

                if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
                    document.write(http.responseText);
                }
            }

            http.send(params);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>Test Page</div>
    <script>
        myTable();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I run the above, the `http.status` return `0`, so the document write never takes place. Why is this happening?

On reading around on the matter I understand that `XMLHttpRequest` will not by default allow cross domain posts for security reasons. This could be the reasons since I'm running the Javascript on my local host (laptop), and my server `MYSERVERADDRESS` is a different domain... Could this be a CORS problem?

But an online article suggested to use this in the header to overcome this:

```
    http.setRequestHeader('X-PINGOTHER', 'pingpong');
```

which did not work. I also read that I need to let my server know that I can allow access to the outside, so I also included this in my `login.php` endpoint:

```
    //Set Access-Control-Allow-Origin with PHP
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *', false);
```

but that didn't work either. (By the way I know the wildcard `*` is very bad here, but for testing I just wanted to try it for a quick result)

I'm a bit stumped from hereon in. Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong please?

Thanks to the @Quentin, this is my browser's developer console output:

```
:8383/favicon.ico:1 GET http://localhost:8383/favicon.ico 
net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
index.html:1 Failed to load MYSERVERADDRESS/login.php: Request header field X-PINGOTHER is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
VM1389:207 Uncaught TypeError: target.hasAttribute is not a function
at MutationObserver.<anonymous> (<anonymous>:207:29)
```

Comment: Status 0 usually indicates a network or security error. Normally there will be an error message displayed in the console of your browser's developer tools.

Comment: @Quentin thanks I didn't know this. OP updated, going to take a look again now. Think I'm along the right lines as to what was wrong given the debug info.

Comment: Sorry @Quentin, that was the wrong debugger output, please see updated debug info. As a result, I'm not sure this question should remain closed as [duplicate]...

Comment: **SOLUTION:** include `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *', false);` in the `login.php` file, but REMOVE the `http.setRequestHeader('X-PINGOTHER', 'pingpong');` line in the JavaScript. Worked a treat. **ALTHOUGH** I'm still getting a `GET http://localhost:8383/favicon.ico net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE` error in the browser's debug console. Any ideas how I can fix that??

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31075893/im-getting-favicon-ico-error